# Something went wrong when I convert API code to PHP CURL

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to convert API code to curl.

Here is the code.

```
url = config.ERPNEXT_URL + "/api/method/erpnext.hr.doctype.employee_checkin.employee_checkin.add_log_based_on_employee_field"
headers = {
    'Authorization': "token "+ config.ERPNEXT_API_KEY + ":" + config.ERPNEXT_API_SECRET,
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}
data = {
    'employee_field_value' : employee_field_value,
    'timestamp' : timestamp.__str__(),
    'device_id' : device_id,
    'log_type' : log_type
}
```

Here is what I have done.

```
$curl = config.ERPNEXT_URL . "/api/method/erpnext.hr.doctype.employee_checkin.employee_checkin.add_log_based_on_employee_field";
$data = array(
    'employee_field_value' => employee_field_value,
    'timestamp' => timestamp.__str__(),
    'device_id' => device_id,
    'log_type' => log_type
);
$tuCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $curl);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
//set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:token ' . config.ERPNEXT_API_KEY . ":" . config.ERPNEXT_API_SECRET));

$tuData = curl_exec($tuCurl);
if(!curl_errno($tuCurl)){
  echo $tuCurl;
} else {
  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($tuCurl);
}

curl_close($tuCurl);
```

I want to know what is wrong with the CURL code?

Many thanks

Comment: "Something went wrong" isn't a very good description of an error, what is the error?

Comment: The last line of your setopt is `curl_setopt($ch ...`  $ch should be  $tuCurl

Answer (score 0):

curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
change it to 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
first store headres in $headers